# Find the geometrical shapes of the objects that satisfy $|z-w|+|z-v|=r$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the geometrical shapes of the objects that satisfy $|z-w|+|z-v|=r$, where $z$ is an arbitrary complex number and $ w,v$ are known numbers and $r$ is a given positive real number.

I tried squaring both sides. But I am stuck.

Comment: Did you try a specific example?

Comment: putting $w=0$, $v=1$, I have been trying to get a familiar equation, it seems to be a 4 order equation and I am lost there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$|z-z_1|+|z-z_2| = 2k$ (a constant) represent

1. If $2k > |z_1-z_2|\implies$ An ellipse
2. If $2k = |z_1-z_2|\implies $ A line segment
3. If $2k < |z_1-z_2|\implies$ No solution

$r$ in your question is $2k$ here, $z_1 = w$ and $z_2 = v$.

This derives from the thumb-pin construction of an ellipse. The sum of distances of the point from two fixed points (foci) is constant. Here $z_1$ and $z_2$ are the two foci of the ellipse

[image]

As the focal sum approaches the distance between the foci, the ellipse squishes. When it becomes equal to the distance between them, it squishes to a line segment, with end points being the foci.

If the focal sum $(2k)$ is less than the distance between the foci, then no point in the plane satisfies the condition otherwise it would lead to the violation of the triangle inequality.

You may experiment yourself the three ways. It is interesting